# jQuery - If value is equal to any of these, do this

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
if(weather.temp >= 30) {

    $("body").randomClass( sunny );
    $("body").addClass( 'sunny' );
    randno = sunnyquotes[Math.floor( Math.random() * sunnyquotes.length )];
    $('.home-main h1').text( randno );
  } else if (weather.todayCode == 40||39||38||37||35||9||4||3||11) {
    $("body").randomClass( rain );
    $("body").addClass( 'rain' );
    randno = rainquotes[Math.floor( Math.random() * rainquotes.length )];
    $('.home-main h1').text( randno );
  } else if ((weather.temp > 18) && (weather.temp < 30) && (weather.todayCode == 32||30||34)) {
    $("body").randomClass( moderate );
    $("body").addClass( 'moderate' );
    randno = moderatequotes[Math.floor( Math.random() * moderatequotes.length )];
    $('.home-main h1').text( randno );
  } else if (weather.temp <= 18) {
    $("body").randomClass( cold );
    $("body").addClass( 'cold' );
    randno = coldquotes[Math.floor( Math.random() * coldquotes.length )];
    $('.home-main h1').text( randno );

  }
```

and I'm trying to determine weather conditions using Yahoo weather. I'm getting stuck on where it's detecting todayCode.

It falls down on the first else if. I want it to execute only if todayCode matches any one of those numbers. Otherwise go to next else if.

Although it works if I only have one number to detect, eg:

```
else if (weather.todayCode == 40)
```

The way I'm checking multiple numbers is obviously wrong.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

A simple way of achieving the multiple comparison is by the use of an array

```
if ([40,39,38,37,35,9,4,3,11].indexOf(weather.todayCode) > -1)
```

[indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: Nice! +1 for use of indexOf, I didn't think of that!

Answer (score 0):

The comparison is written incorrectly. Try this:

```
...
else if (weather.todayCode == 40 || weather.todayCode == 39 || weather.todayCode == 38) //Add more conditions as necessary
...
```

A better idea is a function that can loop through an array of valid values - more readable, but the above example will fix your immediate problem.

Answer (score 0):

also you can use **$.inarray** :

```
rainCode=[ 40,39,38,37,35,9,4,3,11];
if ($.inArray(weather.todayCode, rainCode) > -1)
     $("body").addClass( 'rain' );
```